# Section header always stays under Tech title

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

On the Jobs page, the Orange bar under Tech header looks like an indicator to show which section you are on, the same way the Orange bar works on the left side Nav bar. Click through each one (Tech, Compensation, Perks, Background, Company), the Orange bar stays under the Tech header.

Jobs - Background section
[image: Jobs - Background section]

Jobs - Tech section
[image: Jobs - Tech section]

Comment: That's a bug. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up, fix is going out to production now